# Change label text color in row chart

Tags: svg, d3.js, dc.js

I am using dc.js  row chart. Something exactly like the day of the week chart in the example of [this page](http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/)

Can someone please suggest how can I change the label colors from white to black.

Comment: In the CSS, use `.dc-chart g.row text {fill: black;}`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Should have done that myself. I was tyring to achieve that using Javascript.

Comment: What shall I now do to this question ? Delete it ? Answer it myself and close it ?

Comment: Normally, if the question was indeed answered by someone else in a comment, you ask the person to post it as an answer and then accept it.

Comment: Please post it as an answer and I will accept it :) .. Thank You!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I your CSS, use `.dc-chart g.row text {fill: black;}`.

Comment: Can you explain how this works?  I thought g.row applied to all g elements having class row.

Comment: You are right, it does. So, in the example given by the OP, there is no inline styling for the `text` elements (or their parent `g` elements with class row) which would have overriden any CSS styling. So, you can go ahead and simply CSS style the `g` elements having class row to whichever color you want and the `text` elements will inherit that (the cascading effect). Here is a minimal [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qtH9q/) illustrating my point.

Answer (score 2):

Furthermore, for those who try with pie charts, the selector for labels is without the `g.row`. i.e. : `.dc-chart text.pie-slice {fill: black;}`